# Given the group $(G,\circ)$ why is a subset of $G$ together with $\circ$ associative as well?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm trying to proof that the subset $H$ of $G$ together with $\circ$ is also a group i.e. a subgroup and I'm stuck in the proof that $(H,\circ)$ is associative.

Comment: By the $o$ in $(H,o)$, I assume you mean the restriction of the function $o: G \times G \rightarrow G$ to $H \times H$.  In that case, you don't know that $H$ can be chosen as a codomain of $o_{|H \times H}$, i.e. $H$ might not be closed under the operation.  So any subset $H$ of $G$ need not be a group.

Comment: Your question is vague. Are you trying to prove a specific subset of a specific group? Some general theorem? Why not post the actual problem you are working on, and the step where you are stuck, rather than making us guess about the context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a$, $b$, and $c$ be in $H$.  Then since $H$ is a subset of $G$, we know $a$, $b$, and $c$  are in $G$ and satisfy the associative law:  $a\circ(b\circ c) = (a\circ b)\circ c$.  Therefore $\circ$ is associative for $H$.

Now, not every subset $H$ of $G$ is a subgroup, but your question seems to imply you've got the other criteria figured out.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, a subset $H$ of a group $G$ is a subgroup when $H$ is a group using the operation of $G$.

In principle, this would require you to check all group properties for $H$:
$H$ is closed under the operation, there is a neutral element, there exists an inverse for each element in $H$, and that the operation is associative.

But since the operation of $H$ is the same as the operation of $G$, just restricted to $H$, it inherits its properties and you only have to check that:

- $H$ is closed under the operation
- $H$ contains the neutral element of $G$ — you don't need to prove that it is a neutral element for $H$
- $H$ contains the inverse in $G$ of each of its element — you don't need to prove that this inverse is an inverse in $H$
- You don't need to prove that the operation is associative in $H$ because it is associative in $G$